# HTML JS select with default option

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a `select` element like the following. When the user selects an option, the `this.handleSelectClass` is called, which in turn renders another input field.(the select statement is within a Bootstrap modal)

```
 <select class="form-control" onChange={this.handleSelectClass}>
          <option>Small</option>
          <option>Medium</option>
          <option>Large</option>
  </select>
```

However, I noticed that if I open the form and select the first option, nothing is rendered. This is probably because React doesn't see any change so it doesn't call `onChange`.

So I tried adding an empty option.

```
<select class="form-control" onChange={this.handleSelectClass}>
              <option><option>
              <option>Small</option>
              <option>Medium</option>
              <option>Large</option>
</select>
```

Now the problem is that after the first selection, the empty option remains in the list of options, which makes the list look ugly and also makes my program throw an error when I select the empty option.

I also tried showing the empty option only when no category is selected.

```
<select class="form-control" onChange={this.handleSelectClass}>
                  {!this.state.categorySelected ? <option></option> : <div></div>}
                  <option>Small</option>
                  <option>Medium</option>
                  <option>Large</option>
</select>
```

However, this also doesn't work because the select element is in a modal. 
If I select `Small` and close the modal, when I open it again the default option will be `Small` rather than the empty option.

How can I make it such that I have a default option for the select every time I open the containing modal? Then, after I make the first selection I want the default option to disappear.

Comment: you can add the option like <option>Please Select</option>

Comment: use `$("#yourmodalID").modal('shown.bs.modal')` to clear select before showing or `$("#yourmodalID").modal('hidden.bs.modal')` to clear after hiding `modal`

Comment: you can call a "change" event on select box when you open form...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a HTML select element, with default selected item you can apply the attributes disabled, selected to the option element.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOvqrL

```
<select class="form-control">
      <option disabled selected>Default option</option>
      <option>Small</option>
      <option>Medium</option>
      <option>Large</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not in React, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

When using `select` and React you'd have to result to [some other trickery](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-select-value) than just using the normal `selected` attribute in order to produce a controlled component with a default value selected.

By adding the `value` prop to the actual `select` you get the same output as a normal HTML select with the `selected` attribute. This coupled with a normal `onChange` handler will make it interactive and nice.

```
var Select = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {selectValue: 'C'};
    },
    onChange: function (event) {
        this.setState({selectValue: event.target.value});
    },
    render: function() {
        return <select value={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.onChange}>
            <option value="A">default</option>
            <option value="B">first</option>
            <option value="C">second</option>
        </select>;
    }
});
```

Comment: I've implemented your code but I still have two of the previous issues:
1.the default option stays there after I make the first selection
2.if I select `first` and then close the modal, the option selected by default will be `first` when I open the modal again